# Формообразующие и словообразующие морфемы (в слове "имена")

Tags: словообразование

Есть ли формообразующий суффикс в слове "имена"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словообразующих морфем нет (приставки, суффикса, постфикса), есть единственный формообразующий суффикс *-ен-*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Так как "ен" прибавляется во всех косвенных падежах, то этот элемент можно считать формообразующим суффиксом (образует форму косвенных падежей существительных на -мя). Правда, привычно мы называем это "наращением -ен".